# JSON split using preg_split in PHP

Tags: php, preg-split

I have different servers

```
$strarrServerIp = array('192.168.123.1','192.168.123.2');
$strarrLogsData = array();
foreach($strarrServerIp as $strServerIp ){
       $strCommand = 'ssh abose@' . $strServerIp . ' cat /srv/www/vhosts/trunk/Logs/Log20130825.psi.log';
        $strarrLogsData[] = shell_exec( $strCommand );

            }
foreach( $strarrLogsData as $strJsonLogData ){
           foreach( preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $strJsonLogData ) as $strJsonLineLog ) {
                                display($strJsonLineLog);
                        }
                }
```

The servers contain files containing JSON logs in this form.

```
 {"timestamp":"2013-08-25 20:35:06 MDT","severity":"INFO","data":"1"}
 {"timestamp":"2013-08-25 20:36:06 MDT","severity":"INFO","data":"15"}
 {"timestamp":"2013-08-25 20:37:06 MDT","severity":"INFO","data":"32"}
 {"timestamp":"2013-08-25 20:38:06 MDT","severity":"INFO","data":"25"}
 {"timestamp":"2013-08-25 20:39:06 MDT","severity":"INFO","data":"5"}
```

I want to separate them into an array

```
array (
    [0] => {"timestamp":"2013-08-25 20:35:06 MDT","severity":"INFO","data":"1"}
    [1] => {"timestamp":"2013-08-25 20:36:06 MDT","severity":"INFO","data":"15"}
    [2] => {"timestamp":"2013-08-25 20:37:06 MDT","severity":"INFO","data":"32"}
    [3] => {"timestamp":"2013-08-25 20:38:06 MDT","severity":"INFO","data":"25"}
    [4] => {"timestamp":"2013-08-25 20:39:06 MDT","severity":"INFO","data":"5"}
)
```

Any suggestions?
I want something better than

```
 preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $strJsonLogData )
```

Comment: Do you expect to have many rows in that file? Maybe you're better off with reading one line at a time. Or you could just explode on newline.

Comment: how you read the file content? can you post that part also?

Answer (score 1):

Try  this, you can also use file() function to get each line separated in an array.

```
$text = '
 {"timestamp":"2013-08-25 20:35:06 MDT","severity":"INFO","data":"1"} {"timestamp":"2013-08-25 20:36:06 MDT","severity":"INFO","data":"15"}
 {"timestamp":"2013-08-25 20:37:06 MDT","severity":"INFO","data":"32"}
 {"timestamp":"2013-08-25 20:38:06 MDT","severity":"INFO","data":"25"}
 {"timestamp":"2013-08-25 20:39:06 MDT","severity":"INFO","data":"5"}';

$array =  preg_split("#}.*?{#s", $text );

$array = array_map("trim", $array);
print_r($array);


//using preg_match_all

preg_match_all("#({.*?})#s", $text, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Split by `\n` and use `json_decode` on each line.

Comment: preg_split("/((\r?\n)|(\r\n?))/", $strJsonLogData ) already does that . I want a custom function which will separate even if they are on the same line.